# Updating an SQL field with the same field in another table when condition is met

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have the below VBA code where I'm trying to update a column `CountryID` (ShortText field) with the `CountryID` (ShortText field) from another table when the `StoreID` (ShortText field) match. For the life of me though I can't get this code to work.

```
Private Sub btnUpdateColumn2_Click()
    Dim t As TableDef
    For Each t In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If t.Name Like "PeriodDate_*" Then DoCmd.RunSQL " UPDATE " & t.Name & " SET " & t.Name & ".CountryID = dlookup("[CountryID]", Structure, "[StoreID]" =  [" & t.Name & "].[StoreID]) WHERE [" & t.Name & "].StoreID IS NULL; "
    Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you complicating with looping through the TableDef object? Could it not be as simple as,

```
CurrentDB.Execute "UPDATE theTableName INNER JOIN secondTable ON theTableName.StoreID = secondTable.StoreID_FK SET " & _
                  "theTableName.CountryID = secondTable.fieldName;"
```

Comment: It's actually a series of tables that it is going through

Comment: It worked. I just append it in one step, run it, then break it back out. Thank you for the help